# What will Sony do if someone uses my account as primary on another ps4 without my knowledge?

Tags: ps4, psn

What will Sony do if someone uses my account as primary on another ps4 without my knowledge?
Will the account be banned? Or will the other guy that has my account as primary be banned? After how long? I have no credit card on my account so I don't care too much but I want to know.

He uses my account on his ps4 as a primary account. I think to use my digital games as free (Sharing, but without my knowledge).

Comment: Hi John - just to make sure I understand your question: You're asking if someone uses your account on their PS4? And makes that PS4 their primary PS4?

Comment: i update the question

Comment: PSN accounts are difficult to hack. They had to be given access at some point - whether by trading in the system and no clearing it (or the recipient not clearing account info) or by giving the access to someone without having set your system as the home or primary (initial setup asks if you want to do this)

Comment: Did you all catch that "without my knowledge" in the first line, and then "He uses my account on his ps4 as a primary account. I think to use my digital games as free" at the end. Clearly this is ***not*** without you knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, sadly, is not much.

If your account was used on another PS4 and that PS4 was made into your account's primary PS4, you just have to wait. A PSN account can only have one active PS4, and you can only deactivate a PS4 by either having physical access to it or using your account-wide deactivation, which you can do once every 6 months. So for 6 months, the other PS4 will be your active one and you will not be able to use remote downloading. You can still purchase games through Sony's web store or the PS4 store, and install them normally. You won't be able to play these games (anything you do not own a disc for) without being connected to PSN.

When this happened to me I contacted Sony's customer support and they informed me that there was nothing they could do. They are not allowed to refund your account-wide deactivation, nor can they remotely deactivate a PS4. To my knowledge, Sony doesn't punish either party in these cases.

My advice is:

- Figure out when your PS4 was deactivated. Mark the date 6 months in the future as the time you will need to use your account wide deactivation.
- **Change your PSN account credentials.** I would highly recommend using a strong password (something generated by a secure source, not something you think up) and using a password manager to keep it safe. There are numerous options here and elaboration is outside of the scope of Arqade.
- If you used the same account name/password combination elsewhere (you should try to avoid doing this in general), change those as well.

Comment: So the other guy will not ban ? and something else is that i can't purchase game and other stuff in my ps4 ?

Comment: The other guy will not be banned (to my knowledge). You can still buy and install games as normal, but you won't be able to have your PS4 remotely download them.

Comment: i'm sorry my english is a little bad :) what is ps4 remotely download for game ?

Comment: If you use Sony's web store (https://store.playstation.com/) while logged in you can have games remotely download and install to your PS4 provided it is on or in rest mode. It's an easy to miss feature, but nice if you buy a game while at work and want to play it when you get home :)

Answer (score 2):

If you remove a console as primary they aren't banned, they simply cannot access your PSN content unless they are connected to PSN at the time.

Comment: unless they are connected to PSN at the time : can u please explain more ?

Comment: HI John, so any console that isn't the 'primary' console, must be signed into PSN to accesss PSN provided content. If you aren't signed in to PSN, then it'll tell you that you don't have access to that content, and won't be able to play/view/use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not true , You need to contact sony live chat and you need to  request deacitvate all putting your PSN serial number and within 24Hours you should get option to activate again.

Comment: When I spoke with Sony support (early 2015) I was informed they aren't allowed to refund the deactivation anymore. Have you experienced them doing so more recently?